# Get a unique numeric ID from a String

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an app which should help me to translate some text area, based on Laravel to have a cloud based dictionar to share with other people.

My question is: looking trough php function i found hash crc32 md5 sha1, which function is more fast?? The security is not necessary, I just need a checksum for connect the original language to the other using the same checksum

Ex: English is the original language

English table "Hello Wolrd" -> id (checksum) 29434089525
German table id 29434089525 will return "Hallo Welt"
Italin table id 29434089525 wiil have "Ciao Mondo"

The table have relationship so I will get in one time all the translation with a query.

The String usually are not longher than 200char, but can be more than 50.000, so I need to consider a possible collision??

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest hash for non-cryptographic uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665247/fastest-hash-for-non-cryptographic-uses)

Comment: How many things are you hashing in a single PHP request? If the number is small, you probably won't notice a difference in algorithms. Luckily, this is also something you could easily test with your setup, too.